# Not able to assign month,day and year into local variables in mysql stored procedure even though data is there

Tags: mysql

I have to extract day, month and year of a date into variable and then do some updation on table

Problem I am having is that though i am able to get the result set by the local fields alway appear null

Mysql query is

```
DECLARE ExistingRecordYear INT;
    DECLARE ExistingRecordMonth INT;
    DECLARE ExistingRecordDay INT;
    DECLARE CountRecords SMALLINT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) , ExistingRecordYear = YEAR(updatedon),
    ExistingRecordMonth = MONTH(updatedon), ExistingRecordDay = DAY(updatedon) 
    FROM  `transactions` 
    WHERE `issuer_id` = _issuer_id 
    AND `msisdn` = _msisdn ;
```

Though updatedon is not a nullable field and my count result is 1 but i am still seeing null in all three fields of month,year,and day

Please help me in it

Comment: You're probably looking for `SELECT ... INTO`

Comment: What's the reason for marking the question as negative?
Admin please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `select` statement, you use `:=` to assign variables, not `=`.  In addition, you probably want your variables to have a prefix to distinguish them from columns.  Something like:

```
DECLARE v_ExistingRecordYear INT;
DECLARE v_ExistingRecordMonth INT;
DECLARE v_ExistingRecordDay INT;
DECLARE v_CountRecords SMALLINT;

SELECT v_CountRecords := COUNT(*) , v_ExistingRecordYear := YEAR(updatedon),
       v_ExistingRecordMonth := MONTH(updatedon), v_ExistingRecordDay := DAY(updatedon) 
FROM  `transactions` 
WHERE `issuer_id` = _issuer_id AND `msisdn` = _msisdn ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon for the hint
Following query works
DECLARE lv_ExistingRecordYear INT;
    DECLARE lv_ExistingRecordMonth INT;
    DECLARE lv_ExistingRecordDay INT;
    DECLARE lv_CountRecords INT;
  
    SELECT @lv_CountRecords := COUNT(*) , @lv_ExistingRecordYear := YEAR(updatedon),
    @lv_ExistingRecordMonth := MONTH(updatedon), @lv_ExistingRecordDay := DAY(updatedon) 
    FROM  `transactions_total` 
    WHERE `issuer_id` = _issuer_id 
    AND `trans_mode` = _trans_mode 
    AND `msisdn` = _msisdn ;